# Xcode 6.1: Lexical or Preprocessor Issue 'queue' file not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I'm creating an iPhone app in Xcode 6.1 (Objective-C) and suddenly (in a file that I didn't edit) Xcode can't find the file 'queue'.

Normally I would add the file in *Build Phases -> Compile Sources* , but this is a system file that I can't open in Finder, though when I **CMD + Left click** on `#include <queue>` it opens the file.

I've cleaned the project with **CMD + alt + shift + K** and I checked similar questions on stack overflow and tried the answers, but obviously without success.

I'm quite new to OSX, Xcode and Objective C, so I'm sorry if I'm missing something simple here.

Comment: Umm, that seems like a C++ code. I suppose compiler is not recognising C++. I wonder why you need that though.

Comment: @AjithRNayak That's it! I had to change the *.m file that uses the C++-header to *.mm which is Objective-C++. Thanks a lot! - edit: I can't seem to upvote your comment..